# How do I properly convert a string to decimal in my linq query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

In my C# MVC 5 application, I am trying to use a linq query to convert a column in my sql server table that is an NVarChar to a decimal and display it in the view.

I know that if I was to do a simple SQL query or was using webforms I could simply do the following:

```
Select Sum(Cast(GrandTotal as decimal)) as GrandTotal From [myDB].[dbo].[Table] 
WHERE Year = '2017'
```

How would I do this in linq? This is what I tried:

```
public ActionResult Total()
{
    var model = (from p in db.Table
                where p.Year.Equals("2017")
                select decimal.Parse(p.GrandTotal)).Sum();

    return View(model);
}
```

The error is as follows:
**LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Decimal Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression**

**Not a duplicate**

The title is similar but the solution is different. In addition I was able to resolve the issue by use of the solution given. The question that you marked this as a duplicate of had no clear resolution

Comment: I was able to get this to work: `db.Table.Where(m => m.Year.Equals("2017")).Select(m => m.GrandTotal).ToList().ConvertAll(m => decimal.Parse(m)).Sum();`

Comment: @Gavin: That's LINQ-To-Objects.

Comment: @SamAxe The `.ToList()` executes the query, then we are dealing with LINQ-To-Objects.

Comment: Pretty sure that's what I just said.

Comment: Oh come on @SamAxe, you cant dog him for providing the exact thing you post as an answer

Comment: @Mike_G: I'm certainly not.  There's absolutely nothing wrong with Gavin's answer.  I was simply pointing out that Gavin was using LINQ-To-Objects to perform the task, and not LINQ-To-Entities.  It wasn't mentioned in his comment - so who knows if they knew what they were using, and also making it clear to the OP what technology was being used.   The comment back to me is superfluous - it just reiterates what I had literally just commented.

Comment: It's not possible with LINQ to Entities. Why people make the things harder by storing numeric/date/time data as strings is a mistery.

Comment: One has to ask why you are storing decimal values as strings in your database. You should be using columns with type `money`. Is this something you can change?

Comment: I did use money. It has the same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unaware of a LINQ-To-Entities function that can do this.  Id do it using LINQ-To-Objects:

```
var result = (from p in db.Table where "2017" == p.Year select p).ToList();
var model = (from p in result select decimal.Parse(p.GranTotal)).Sum();
```

Comment: This solution gives me a different error when I try to fire up the view 

`The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Decimal', but this dictionary requires a model item of type`

Comment: Well that's an entirely different problem and should be posted as a different question.  But before posing the question you should read the words and let them sink in for a moment.  You'll get it.

Comment: I resolved it. Thanks man!